# User registration with additional information. React / Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to make a function for the admin to add new user to my React/Firebase web app with additional information in a Firestore collection. I manage to create the user (they show up in the authentication tab) but the additionall information do not register. Thoughts... and prayers and most of all solutions would be appreciated :). Thanks for any help.

I've tried diffrent solutions, this is the last one that is not working (the user registers but not the additional information).

```
import firebase from 'the path';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Form, Button} from 'react-bootstrap';
```

```
class addNewUserFunc extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.addNewUser = this.addNewUser.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
```

```
addNewUser = (newUser) => {
        newUser.preventDefault();
        firebase
            .auth()
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                this.state.email, 
                this.state.password)
            .then((resp) => {
                const db = firebase.firestore();
                return db.collection('users').doc(resp.user.uid).set({
                userCompany: this.state.userCompany,
                })

            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log(newUser);


            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;

            if (errorCode == 'auth/weak-password') {
              alert('The password is too weak.');
            } else {
              alert(errorMessage);
            }
            console.log(error);



        });
```

Should create a new user and and store additional information in a firestore collection. The collection document name should be same as user id.

Comment: Have you tried inserting data into your firebase collection outside user creation? Does that work?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is that possible if you want the user id?

Comment: Design-wise it is cleaner to separate the two steps. Step 1 create an account, Step 2 add account data.